# Error Connecting to Hive with keytab kerberos authentication

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, hive, kerberos

I am trying to connect to hive in remote CDH cluster.

Dependency used:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <classifier>standalone</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Code:

```
  val url: String = "jdbc:hive2://ip-11-11-5-228.eu-central-1.compute.internal:10000/test;" +
    "principal=hive/my@test-TELEKOM.COM;"
  val driver = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
  val fullTableName = "test.student_data"
  val keytab_path = "/etc/my.keytab"

  val conf:org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
  System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "/etc/krb5.conf")
  System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", "my-test.COM")
  System.setProperty("HADOOP_CONF_DIR", "/etc/hadoop/conf/")
  System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", "ip-11-11-5-228.eu-central-1.compute.internal")
  conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos")
  conf.set("hadoop.security.authorization", "true")
  UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf)
  UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("hive/my@test-TELEKOM.COM",
    keytab_path)
  Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")

DriverManager.getConnection(url)
```

Error on running:

javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

I have placed the keytab file in local which i have received but still getting the error

Comment: Can you kinit with the keytab on the machine?  kinit -t /etc/my.keytab hive/my@test-TELEKOM.COM

Comment: Would you consider using Jaas instead of setting all the config in code?  it might be a lot cleaner. (and you might find better support as then it's a generic issue)

Answer (score 1):

Can you validate that the user that is trying to use the keytab file can kinit with it. (Does the keytab file have the correct permissions?)

Login as the user that the scala will be running as and perform:

```
kinit -kt /etc/my.keytab hive/my@test-TELEKOM.COM
```

It's likely the case that the scala user should own the keytab. This is a Really common thing I forget to do all the time.

Comment: Great to hear.   If you found this answer  helpful please upvote it.  If you feel comfortable please mark this as the answer.